# Way To Use Setter When Setting Element Within Array

Tags: c#, arrays, setter, getter

I have a class that looks like

```
public class MyArray
{
    public bool is_set = false;

    private int[] _myarray;
    public int[] myarray
    {
        get{return _myarray;}
        set
        {
            _myarray = value;
            is_set = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But in the following code after setting an item inside the array (4th line) the is_set boolean reads false.

```
    MyArray a = new MyArray();
    a.myarray = new int[1];
    a.is_set = false;
    a.myarray[0] = 5;
```

Is there anyway to make it so that the class will alert me when I set an element within the array? Arrays can be interchangeable with list or observable collection or whatever.

Comment: Apparently you want an indexer in your class... you Array class is not really an array anyway.. it just exposes a property of type array.. Any answer would probably not make much sense (IMHO), unless you can explain what is the real problem you are trying to solve? because many other classes out there, might raise such events, or allow you to "observe" changes to collections in many ways.

Comment: I'm working with WPF and want to make it so that I get a property changed event when I alter an element within an array within a custom class.

Comment: That code actually uses the **getter** of your object, not the setter. It must first _get_ the array member of your object, so it can then call the setter of the indexed property that belongs to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes like `ObservableCollection<T>` already implement kind of feature you want to use with WPF.. Look at them and see if they fit your needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ObservableCollection does notify when changing the array itself (add, remove, clear) but not when the elements are changed. I just subbed in ObservableCollection<int> for my array in the example and had the same results.

Comment: Ah just looked through and found the event you were probably talking about. Just had to hook up a function to the CollectionChanged event and got everything working. Thanks.